# HTML - Format text content based on current date

Tags: javascript, html, css, format

I'm new to web developing and trying to make some text on HTML look striketroughted based on the current date.

I have a table with all month appointments. Here a piece of code:

```
<tr>
    <td><span>04/Oct/2020</span></td>
    <td><span>sunday</span></td>
    <td><span>07:00</td>
    <td><span>Cris and Gibson</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>09/Oct/2020</span></td>
    <td><span>friday</span></td>
    <td><span>07:00</td>
    <td><span>Mark and Sonia</td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is (assuming today is 7th Oct) create script that compares the date of each line and strikethrough the set of code that in a past date. (in this case, the first set - 4th Oct).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i;
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

var dates = document.getElementsByClassName('date');

for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  if (dates[i].innerHTML !== today) {
    dates[i].classList.add('past');
  }
}
```

```css
.past {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td><span class="date">04/10/2020</span></td>
    <td><span>sunday</span></td>
    <td><span>07:00</td>
    <td><span>Cris and Gibson</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="date">07/10/2020</span></td>
    <td><span>Today</span></td>
    <td><span>07:00</td>
    <td><span>Mark and Sonia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="date">09/10/2020</span></td>
    <td><span>friday</span></td>
    <td><span>07:00</td>
    <td><span>Mark and Sonia</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm! But, I made just one modification: in if statement where the condition was different (!==) I change to less (<) to strikethrough entire dates before today. Again, thank you!

Comment: @MendelyeevMoura Happy to hear that your welcome give it a thumbs up :)